# dealing with received gcm push notification in different activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I'm new to android development. I am able to push notification to devices. In my application, there are three different activities. I followed the google gcm client example to receive the notifications. Now i need to deal with the received push message differently according which activity is active. I understood that this can be solved with registering multiple receivers for push msgs. I dont know how to do that. Can you guys help me with this ? please/...

Comment: The idea behind GCM is that no activity need be running when a message is received. When one comes in, then the phone wakes up if necessary. You can decide which activity should deal with the message by checking the elements in the data attached to the message.

Comment: @NickT The app is an Instant messaging app and i'm using push msgs to deliver the actual msg. So the app is in use, if the msg is received I need to consume it in different activities !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register different broadcast receivers in each activity. Then broadcast GCM messages  from the `GCMIntentService` through `Intent` to these activities.

Comment: can you elaborate on the above idea pls ?

Comment: In the onMessage method of GCMIntentService check where the message should be passed (get some parameter from intent which will tell you to which activity message should be passed). Then create appropriate Intent and send it with sendBrodcast method.

Comment: pls man i'm getting what need to be done but i need some example.

Comment: The sample app available on the Google site (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html) has everything that you need. Simply in each activity register different broadcast receiver.