# Handling same type of many Broadcast receivers?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am developing an app which enables users to register for many automatic services like auto sms reply and acting on bluetooth changed etc.
Now a user can set many auto reply rules. I have saved these rules with conditions in database. for example if an sms come from 123 it will reply with a message "hello" and if an sms come from 456 it will reply with "i am fine".
now the problem is i have rules saved in database and i want my broadcast receiver can tell me which rule is being triggered?
question is.
Is it ok to register many receivers for each rule, that can be 10, 15 or 50?
and is there a way i can pass a number 'ruleId' with each receiver at registering so that on receiving it can give me that id so that i can act for that specific rule only?

pleASE HELP me find the solution or what is the correct way out of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hey i also has the same requirement. I need to respond when any push notification is received in different activities based on the current active activity.

[dealing with received gcm push notification in different activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198458/dealing-with-received-gcm-push-notification-in-different-activities)