# Send gcm messages to different application activty

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

Im new to android application development and im developing an app that uses GCM messaging. This app registers to my php webserver. I follow some tutorials about gcm but im really confused. This application has 3 activities:

1. `NewsActivity.java` - displays new information and special topics.
2. `MemoActivity.java`- displays memo.

   3  `EventsActivity.java` - displays important information about special events.

My problem:

1. How can the server send gcm messages to specific android activity. For example i want to send gcm message to  NewsActivity.java ONLY which means that the message will only be displayed in that specific activity?
2. How can the app determine if that message can only be displayed on specific activity?

   I don't know where to start. Any information you can provide me would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you study the GCM BroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCM Server sends the message to the app. It is received in the Broadcast receiver. There you can find which of your activity is visible by setting a flag to some value in every activity or by other means. Or follow this [dealing with received gcm push notification in different activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198458/dealing-with-received-gcm-push-notification-in-different-activities)